# Retrieving and displaying array values in click functionality

Tags: javascript, html, angular

- I am trying to display values of different arrays using angular5 using click functionality
- Elements of an array are displayed when writing under ngFor condition
- Array values are displayed in the console under the click function, bu no idea of displaying values in he browser
- I have attached the relevant files for the issue and kindly provide your suggestion for the same
- The entire code for the component and html files are available in gist and their links are provided as below:
- pro.component.ts:
  https://gist.github.com/aarivalagan/d44b6f256f35bf71a8d477dad025977f 
  pro.component.html: https://gist.github.com/aarivalagan/bedab707fb5c1491df415d84b7bba8e2

pro.component.ts

```
this.vList.forEach((v: any) => {
            v.Completed ? this.trainCom++ : this.trainpen++;
            v.isQCompleted ? this.qCount++ : this.qPen++;
          });
        });
        this.vList.forEach((v: any) => {
          if(!v.Completed) {
            this.pen_cour.push(v.name);
          } else {
            this.com_cour.push(v.name);
          }
          if(!v.isQCompleted) {
            this.pen_cour_q.push(v.name);
          } else {
            this.com_cour_q.push(v.name);
          }
        });
      });
cour_Com(){
    this.com_cour.forEach(element => {
      this.cour1 =this.com_cour;
      console.log("hello");
      console.log(this.cour1);
    });
  }
```

pro.component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="cour_Comp()" >View</button>
  <div id="demo" *ngFor='let cour of this.com_cour'>
    <span *ngIf="this.com_cour != NULL"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="this.com_cour != NULL">{{course}}</button></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You've done `let cour of this.com_cour`, which should be `let cour of com_cour` as you don't need `this` within the template. Also, each item can be referenced using `cour`, so use `{{cour}}` to get the value, assuming it is a string

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you. As a side note you're using `ng-show`, from AngularJS, not Angular

Comment: @user184994...thanks for your reply...I tried with your suggestions...array values are displayed in the UI but values are not displayed on clicking view button (click functionality)...can you provide any suggestion for the issue

Comment: @lealceldeiro...thanks for your reply...I took your suggestion and provided gist links for both component and html code relevant to the issue